# Laravel bind input to variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Searched for the entire internet and found nothing related.

I want to bind the paginate variable from input `<input name="showLimit">`

```
public function index()
{
    $showLimit = Input::get('showLimit');
    $drivers = Driver::paginate($showLimit);
    return view('manage.driver', compact('drivers'));
}
```

Error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use depency injection on the [`Request` class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#accessing-the-request).

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request) {
    $showLimit = $request->get('showLimit');
    $drivers = Driver::paginate($showLimit);
    return view('manage.driver', compact('drivers'));
}
```

Comment: @FransiscoWijaya I've read your question and "I need it to update automatically" is not in there

Comment: @apokryfos but with binding, it will automatically sync one another right?

Comment: I think you're thinking of things like Vue or Angular which are client side. Laravel is server side so it only "binds" things on a per-request basis.

Comment: so what should i do? :'(

Comment: Use Vue. The basic boilerplate of laravel includes it. There's tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

it seem that you have wrong path for the `Input` class

```
$showLimit = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('showLimit');
$drivers = Driver::paginate($showLimit);
return view('manage.driver', compact('drivers'));
```